Time efficient way of conducting vc relax calculations while mainting accurate results at the same time
I believe this VC-relaxation calculation will take a significant amount of time to successfully complete. Referring to the literature (which indicates that the vanadium substitution atom is positioned a few angstroms above the graphene plane in after the vc-relaxation), I plan to specify the vanadium atom's position as 1 angstrom above the graphene plane in the input script as shown below, anticipating that it will take less time to complete the calculation. Does anyone know of a more time efficient way of conducting this VC relaxation than this method?
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'vc-relax',
    prefix      = 'VsubG_8x8',
    restart_mode = 'restart',
    ! otudir      = '/tmp',
    pseudo_dir  = './',
    etot_conv_thr = 1.0d-6        
 /

 &SYSTEM
    ibrav     = 0,
    celldm(1) = 37.18980746,
    nat  = 128,
    ntyp = 2,
    nspin = 2,
    starting_magnetization(1)=0.2,
    starting_magnetization(2)=0.5,
    ecutwfc = 60,
    ecutrho = 480, 

    occupations = 'smearing',
    smearing = 'mv',
    degauss = 0.01,
 /
 
 &ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-8
    mixing_mode = 'local-TF'
 /
 &IONS
    ion_dynamics = 'bfgs'
 /
 &CELL
    cell_dynamics = 'bfgs'
 /
 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
   C  12.0107 C.pbe-rrkjus.UPF
   V  50.9415 v_pbe_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF

CELL_PARAMETERS (alat=37.18980746)
   1.000962687   0.000000000  -0.000000000
  -0.500481343   0.866859115  -0.000000000
   0.000000000  -0.000000000   1.016233491
   
ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
C            -0.0000000000        0.0000000000       -0.0000000000
C             1.2312079009        0.7108382119        0.0000000000
C            -1.2311605811        2.1324560034        0.0000000000
C             0.0000000000        2.8433213413       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4623481125        4.2649586612        0.0000000000
C            -1.2311879113        4.9757693133       -0.0000000000
C            -3.6935562460        6.3974502959       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4623480214        7.1082331810       -0.0000000000
C            -4.9247364463        8.5298936744       -0.0000000000
C            -3.6935284856        9.2407319208        0.0000000000
C            -6.1558964869       10.6623487020       -0.0000000000
C            -4.9247363386       11.3732148577       -0.0000000000
C            -7.3870843520       12.7948520387        0.0000000000
C            -6.1559241685       13.5056627214        0.0000000000
C            -8.6182920558       14.9273430399       -0.0000000000
C            -7.3870843230       15.6381267087       -0.0000000000
C             2.4623413649       -0.0000116640       -0.0000000000
C             3.6935764363        0.7108427852        0.0000000000
C             1.2311605811        2.1324560034       -0.0000000000
C             2.4623961292        2.8433096270        0.0000000000
C             0.0000000000        4.2649431019       -0.0000000000
C             1.2311879113        4.9757693133        0.0000000000
C            -1.2311875295        6.3974228343        0.0000000000
C            -0.0000000000        7.1082492383       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4623956656        8.5298823090       -0.0000000000
C            -1.2311600989        9.2407365981       -0.0000000000
C            -3.6935758987       10.6623490326       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4623402416       11.3732031653       -0.0000000000
C            -4.9247359111       12.7948362915       -0.0000000000
C            -3.6935484218       13.5056627652       -0.0000000000
C            -6.1559237705       14.9273158334       -0.0000000000
C            -4.9247362572       15.6381427341        0.0000000000
C             4.9247366000       -0.0000233105        0.0000000000
C             6.1558966864        0.7108427529        0.0000000000
C             3.6935292172        2.1324600845        0.0000000000
C             4.9247364925        2.8432979352        0.0000000000
C             2.4623481125        4.2649586612        0.0000000000
C             3.6935562263        4.9757415388       -0.0000000000
C             1.2311875295        6.3974228343       -0.0000000000
C             2.4623480214        7.1082331810       -0.0000000000
C             0.0000000000        8.5298704204        0.0000000000
C             1.2311600989        9.2407365981        0.0000000000
C            -1.2312078164       10.6623534298        0.0000000000
C             0.0000000000       11.3731915929       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4623883617       12.7948521742        0.0000000000
C            -1.2311801427       13.5056350054        0.0000000000
C            -3.6935483816       14.9273156429       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4623883172       15.6381267300        0.0000000000
C             7.3871325986       -0.0000116085        0.0000000000
C             8.6182649797        0.7108381337       -0.0000000000
C             6.1559444162        2.1324603315       -0.0000000000
C             7.3870768274        2.8433095005        0.0000000000
C             4.9247370306        4.2649740847        0.0000000000
C             6.1559166758        4.9757414421       -0.0000000000
C             3.6935562460        6.3974502959        0.0000000000
C             4.9247363726        7.1082173405        0.0000000000
C             2.4623956656        8.5298823090        0.0000000000
C             3.6935284856        9.2407319208       -0.0000000000
C             1.2312078164       10.6623534298       -0.0000000000
C             2.4623402416       11.3732031653        0.0000000000
C            -0.0000000000       12.7948679192        0.0000000000
C             1.2311801427       13.5056350054       -0.0000000000
C            -1.2311802331       14.9273434271        0.0000000000
C             0.0000000000       15.6381109172       -0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395        0.0000000306        0.0000000000
C            11.0806806994        0.7108381337        0.0000000000
C             8.6183128286        2.1324557516       -0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395        2.8433212422       -0.0000000000
C             7.3871249668        4.2649585915       -0.0000000000
C             8.6182850033        4.9757691689       -0.0000000000
C             6.1559172705        6.3974499699       -0.0000000000
C             7.3871248505        7.1082330686        0.0000000000
V             4.9247364463        8.5298936744        1.0000000000
C             6.1559442324        9.2407319051        0.0000000000
C             3.6935758987       10.6623490326       -0.0000000000
C             4.9247363386       11.3732148577        0.0000000000
C             2.4623883617       12.7948521742       -0.0000000000
C             3.6935484218       13.5056627652        0.0000000000
C             1.2311802331       14.9273434271        0.0000000000
C             2.4623883172       15.6381267300       -0.0000000000
C            12.3118130805       -0.0000116085        0.0000000000
C            13.5430489926        0.7108427529       -0.0000000000
C            11.0806328505        2.1324557516        0.0000000000
C            12.3118688517        2.8433095005       -0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395        4.2649425155       -0.0000000000
C            11.0806606757        4.9757691689        0.0000000000
C             8.6182849810        6.3974224369        0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395        7.1082490516        0.0000000000
C             7.3870772815        8.5298816578       -0.0000000000
C             8.6183126879        9.2407364368        0.0000000000
C             6.1558964869       10.6623487020       -0.0000000000
C             7.3871323794       11.3732030977       -0.0000000000
C             4.9247359111       12.7948362915        0.0000000000
C             6.1559241685       13.5056627214       -0.0000000000
C             3.6935483816       14.9273156429        0.0000000000
C             4.9247362572       15.6381427341        0.0000000000
C            14.7742090790       -0.0000233105       -0.0000000000
C            16.0053692428        0.7108427852       -0.0000000000
C            13.5430012629        2.1324603315       -0.0000000000
C            14.7742091865        2.8432979352       -0.0000000000
C            12.3118207123        4.2649585915       -0.0000000000
C            13.5430290033        4.9757414421        0.0000000000
C            11.0806606981        6.3974224369       -0.0000000000
C            12.3118208286        7.1082330686       -0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395        8.5298702064       -0.0000000000
C            11.0806329912        9.2407364368        0.0000000000
C             8.6182654540       10.6623529732       -0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395       11.3731915089       -0.0000000000
C             7.3870843520       12.7948520387        0.0000000000
C             8.6182925325       13.5056349671        0.0000000000
C             6.1559237705       14.9273158334        0.0000000000
C             7.3870843230       15.6381267087       -0.0000000000
C            17.2366043142       -0.0000116640        0.0000000000
C            18.4677377782        0.7108382119       -0.0000000000
C            16.0054164619        2.1324600845       -0.0000000000
C            17.2365495499        2.8433096270        0.0000000000
C            14.7742086485        4.2649740847       -0.0000000000
C            16.0053894528        4.9757415388       -0.0000000000
C            13.5430284086        6.3974499699        0.0000000000
C            14.7742093065        7.1082173405       -0.0000000000
C            12.3118683976        8.5298816578        0.0000000000
C            13.5430014467        9.2407319051       -0.0000000000
C            11.0806802251       10.6623529732        0.0000000000
C            12.3118132997       11.3732030977       -0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395       12.7948672104        0.0000000000
C            11.0806531466       13.5056349671        0.0000000000
C             8.6182920558       14.9273430399       -0.0000000000
C             9.8494728395       15.6381109555       -0.0000000000
   

K_POINTS automatic
   10 10 1   0 0 0


Little confusing here, why Kpoint mesh is 1 in Z . In x and y direction 10 is also too much.  Why volume relaxation if it is graphene sheet. Shouldn't be only minimize in-plane lattice parameters or simple atomic relaxation

@Pranavkumar the kpoint mesh should be 1 in z, since it's only a 2D material; however, I agree about the cell relaxation, it definitely should not be relaxed in z.
